# ASP.NET Core - acessing object from razor in code behind

Tags: c#, json, razor, asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP.NET Core, so I'm still trying to understand it.

I was trying to access an object from code behind. Is it possible? I have been trying and searching for hours and I have yet to understand it. I'll leave some of what I've tried bellow, which apparently isn't working. If I could get some insight on this I'd very much appreciate it.

In classic ASP.NET I always to the id approach from code behind to the client side. But now I've been asked to try a different approach. In this case, a loop. How can I do this? I've also been reading the microsoft documentation but I still can't understand this. I'd appreciate some help.

Here's a spinnet of what I tried:

```
// The controller
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public GetInfo GetInfo { get; set; }
        public IActionResult Offers()
        {

            GetInfo = new GetInfo();

            GetInfo.GetOffers();

            return View();
        }
    }


// The GetInfo class which gets data from a JSON file
public class GetInfo
    {
        public Offer.RootObject Offers { get; set; }

        public void GetOffers()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("whatever.com");
            // client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

            var request = new RestRequest("Home/GetOffersJson", Method.GET);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;

            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Offer.RootObject>(content);

            Offers = new Offer.RootObject
            {
                total = obj.total,
                data = obj.data
            };


        }
    }

// The View file, where I'm trying to access the object from c#, which supposedly is 'loaded'
@model HostBookingEngine_HHS.Models.GetInfo;
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Offers";


}

    @foreach (var item in Model.Offers.data)
    {
        <span asp-validation-for="@item.TextTitle"></span>

    }
```

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: you have to pass the model to the view. e.g return View(GetInfo);

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work just now, as suggested on the answer bellow. And that was it. Still, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have `Offers` available on view, you have to pass model to a view as an argument to `View()` method. So in your case you have to make your action look like:

```
public IActionResult Offers()
{
    GetInfo = new GetInfo();
    GetInfo.GetOffers();
    return View(GetInfo);
}
```

Comment: That's it! I get it now. Although I declared a model on the client-side I had to pass it in order to access it. Oh, this can be so confusing. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

asp.net core view has four over loading these are

```
public virtual ViewResult View();
public virtual ViewResult View(string viewName, object model);
public virtual ViewResult View(object model);
public virtual ViewResult View(string viewName);
```

ASP.NET Core can use all of these with exact parameter 
You can pass your model object using **Public Virtual ViewResult View(object model);**

You need to pass your model object like this

```
return View(GetInfo);
```

which actually access your parameter object

```
@model HostBookingEngine_HHS.Models.GetInfo;
```

Also there are several method of passing data to view

Like ViewBag,ViewData which also grab the value in each request.